# install python package in Azure ml

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

i am trying to install python package called delta-sharing. I was able to install (**pip install delta-sharing**) successfully in computer terminal. But when i try to **import delta_sharing** in the notebook, it is not found. I am wondering if i miss anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might installed the module for different environment. What I recommend is go to you notebook and run a cell with this code:

```
!pip install delta-sharing
```

Comment: Thanks i figured it out that delta-sharing is only working for Python 3.8 and above